# last-child not working css/html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to have a row of four divs.

```css
.frontpage {
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frontpage img {
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.frontpage a:last-child img {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontpage">RETRO
  <br>
  <a href="retro/index.html">
    <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="frontpage">RETRO
    <br>
    <a href="retro/index.html">
      <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
    </div>

    <div class="frontpage">RETRO
      <br>
      <a href="retro/index.html">
        <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <p>TEXT</p>
      <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
      </div>

      <div class="frontpage">RETRO
        <br>
        <a href="retro/index.html">
          <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
```

As you can see im trying to get that last div a 0px margin using last-child. But i can’t seem to get rid of the margin.

Comment: Actually, the `last-child` is being applied to the `<a>`, not to the div.

Comment: Are `.frontpage` elements intended to be siblings? If so, you're missing their closing `</div>`s.

Comment: No there the parent, the readmore is a sibling in this div content. I forgot the closing div in my code. Sorry

Answer (score 7):

You have to move selector to `.frontpage`.

```
.frontpage:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the OP may want to remove the margin from the `<div>` itself: "im trying to get that last div a 0px margin using last-child"

Comment: From the div i think. If that is posible? Because the div has the margin.

Comment: Your html code is invalid, you have to add one more closing `</div>` after each row.

Answer (score 1):

adding the missing closing div to each solved the problem

```css
.frontpage {
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.frontpage img {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.frontpage a:last-child img {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontpage">RETRO
  <br>
  <a href="retro/index.html">
    <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="frontpage">RETRO
  <br>
  <a href="retro/index.html">
    <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="frontpage">RETRO
  <br>
  <a href="retro/index.html">
    <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="frontpage">RETRO
  <br>
  <a href="retro/index.html">
    <img src="images/name1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="retro/index.html">READ MORE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```